# Angular2: Catch Template parse errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to know if it's possible to catch all kind of errors like `Template parse errors`. When I receive an error like this one, angular doesn't finish loading, that's normal since there's an error. But, I would like to print the error on the page just so it's easier for me to know there's an error since the loading takes some time. Is there any way to do that?

Some time, the error is catched by the `System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) {console.error(err);)` function in my index file, but not for a `Template parse error`.

Comment: Are you binding templates dynamically?

Comment: I get the errors on the start of the application. But I use my components in my html pages or dynamically using  `createComponent()`. And of course, my templates are located either in the template or templateUrl attribute of the components.

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing. I would like to catch it log it in some custom way but I can't find a way to catch it and default ErrorHandler is not used to log uncaught errors.